# Recursively parse/analyze go ast

Tags: go

What is the best way to recursively parse the go AST, from method callee -> caller (or vice versa)? Similar to something like the [Goland Call Hierarchy tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/viewing-structure-and-hierarchy-of-the-source-code.html). I'm trying to write a program to recursively add a parameter to a bunch of methods, all of their parents (recursively), and all callsites.

To my understanding, the [analysis package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis) only runs on a package by package basis.

Comment: Use the [`go/parser`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser@go1.18) package to parse Go code.